# React - the preferred way to perform an action when leaving page / changing route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm writing a react app which uses `react-router-dom` for routing. For one of the routes I have to perform an action when the user leaves (perform api request & stop the timer).
I can do this either

1. In the cleanup function returned by `useEffect` hook inside the component rendered for that route

or

2. Attach to the router and detect the route changes.

Which way is better? Or perhaps there's some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillUnmount`. However, `useEffect` works just as well!
That is likely the better way to handle this event.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to use react router tools to make effects when your are navigating.

Unmount is kind of side effect of navigation, but maybe could not unmount, or you can unmount that component for other reasons.

if you are using hooks maybe you can use `useLocation` and store what is the current page and do something like this:

```js
function usePageViewTracker() {
  const location = useLocation()
  [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastLocation === 'specialLocation') {
      // call your API
    }
    setLastLocation(location)
  }, [location])

}
```